# ExtJS - How to set a tooltip to a TAB from a Ext.panel.Panel

Tags: extjs, tabs, tooltip, panel

I have a Ext.Tab,Panel where I have multiple tabs created dynamically.

Each of this tabs contains a Ext.panel.panel. What I need to do is to add a tooltip the the tab. I was trying to do something like this:

```
Ext.define('XXX.XXX.XXX.MyCustomPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

setTabTitle: function() {

    title = 'some title';

  try {
    this.setTitle(title);

    this.getHeader().getEl().set({
        'data-qtip': title
    });
  } catch (e) {

  }
}
```

Nevertheless, the tab is not the header so it is not applying the tooltip to the tab

Any idea

Edit:

Also found another way to do this:

```
this.tab.setTooltip('tool tip');
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each tab button is instance of `Ext.tab.Tab` class. When you creating new panel in tab panel, you can specify configuration for tab button by `tabConfig` option.

So in tabConfig option you easily specify tab tooltip by:

```
    tabConfig: {                    
        tooltip: 'Tooltip text'
    }
```

This code create new `Ext.Tab.Panel` with two tabs which have defined tooltip and dynamicly create third one which also have tooltip:

```
   var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [{
            title: 'Foo',
            tabConfig: {                    
                tooltip: 'A Foo tab tooltip'
            }                
        }, {
            title: 'Bar',
            tabConfig: {                    
                tooltip: 'A Bar tab tooltip'
            }
        }]
    });

    var dynamiclyCreatedTab = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
       tabConfig: {
           title: 'Dynamicly created tab',
           tooltip: 'A Dynamicly created tab tooltip'
       } 
    });

    tabPanel.add(dynamiclyCreatedTab);
```

See fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1q8

Comment: yes but I create each tab dynamically. The case you mention consider static items/panels.

Comment: It not depends if you creating tab dynamily or define them in items configuration. The way how to define configuration for tab is same. I have edited previous post to make it more clearly.

Comment: cool but this system are not implementing tabs like that :( anyways I found and added another solution. Thanks!